# How to make logs

Tags: c#, winforms, events, logging, jobs

To explain a little more, I have a Main `Form` which contains a large list of jobs.
Every item in the list is a instance of my class called Jobs.
When an item is clicked, another `Form` is opening, in which user can edit information of selected job. I pass a job object from Main `Form` to details `Form` and edit it through `TextBoxes`, `ComboBoxes` and so on.

Now I need to detect which properties of jobs have changed and write it in log file. I know how to write to log file, but I dont know how to detect which properties have changed.

I could go and write 30 `if` statements in which I would compare starting point with ending point but I have 30 properties and it would be a complete mess.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using events? Textboxes and comboxes have in Winforms have events like "TextChanged" etc, which you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at INotifyPropertyChanged:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

**Example**

```
using log4net;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Form1).FullName);
        public PersonViewPresenter Presenter { get; private set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Presenter = new PersonViewPresenter();
            Presenter.PropertyChanged += Presenter_PropertyChanged;
            AddBindings();
        }

        private void Presenter_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Info($"Property changed {e.PropertyName}");
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            _firstnameTextbox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(nameof(_firstnameTextbox.Text), Presenter, nameof(Presenter.FirstName), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
            _lastnameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(nameof(_lastnameTextBox.Text), Presenter, nameof(Presenter.LastName), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPresenter implementation**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class PersonViewPresenter : ViewPresenterBase
    {
        private string _lastName;
        private string _firstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get => _firstName; set
            {
                if (_firstName != value)
                {
                    _firstName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get => _lastName; set
            {
                if (_lastName != value)
                {
                    _lastName = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class ViewPresenterBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could solve the issue for sure. Maybe, add a sample implementation so it can be visible here.

Comment: Don't forget to `Presenter.PropertyChanged -= Presenter_PropertyChanged;` OnDispose()